# Finding Probability of Gaussian Distribution Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, gaussian

The original question was to model a lightbulb, which are used 24/7, and usually one lasts 25 days. A box of bulbs contains 12. What is the probability that the box will last longer than a year?

I had to use MATLAB to model a Gaussian curve based on an exponential variable.
The code below generates a Gaussian model with mean = 300 and std= sqrt(12)*25.
The reason I had to use so many different variables and add them up was because I was supposed to be demonstrating the central limit theorem. The Gaussian curve represents the probability of a box of bulbs lasting for a # of days, where 300 is the average number of days a box will last.

I am having trouble using the gaussian I generated and finding the probability for days >365. The statement  1-normcdf(365,300, sqrt(12)*25) was an attempt to figure out the expected value for the probability, which I got as .2265. **Any tips on how to find the probability for days>365 based on the Gaussian I generated would be greatly appreciated.**

Thank you!!!

```
  clear all
samp_num=10000000;
param=1/25;
a=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
b=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
c=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
d=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
e=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
f=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
g=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
h=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
i=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
j=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
k=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
l=-log(rand(1,samp_num))/param;
x=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l;


mean_x=mean(x);
std_x=std(x);
bin_sizex=.01*10/param;
binsx=[0:bin_sizex:800];
u=hist(x,binsx);
u1=u/samp_num;

1-normcdf(365,300, sqrt(12)*25)
bar(binsx,u1)
legend(['mean=',num2str(mean_x),'std=',num2str(std_x)]);
```

Comment: What does your Gaussian represent? Is it the number of hours a bulb will last? The number of bulbs remaining in a box or anything else? Please update your post.

Comment: I believe the Gaussian represents the probability of a box of bulbs lasting certain # of days. 300 is usually how long a box will last, the mean.

Comment: Why is your `std=sqrt(12)*25`? Are you sure the answer .2265 is wrong?

Comment: The answer .2265 is right, but thats the expected value, I need to use the Gaussian I generated to extract a similar value, which should be around ~.21. And the std was given to me.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I ran your code and I got  0.22646. It seems correct to me. `normcdf(365,300, sqrt(12)*25)` would be the probability that they last up to a year and `1-normcdf(365,300, sqrt(12)*25)` would be >1 year. It would be better if you used `mean_x` and `stx_` in `normcdf` rather than hard-code the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[f, y]=ecdf(x)` will create an [empirical cdf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/ecdf.html) for the data in `x`. You can then find the probability where it first crosses 365 to get your answer.

Comment: I tried to use [f,y] =ecdf(binsx), which gave me a plot of the probabilities vs days, however when I looked at 365, the probability was around .4579, and since I want >365, 1-.4579=.5421, which does not really make sense. If I look at the Gaussian curve, > 365 is clearly much less than .5. I don't know if I am doing or thinking of this wrong.

Comment: I get 0.7911 => p=0.2089. You want to find the first point where y>365, not take element 365 of f.

Comment: What was the input for your ecdf()?

Comment: x although I reduced sampnum to 10000. It is generating lots of random so I wouldn't expect you to get exactly the same answer, but it should be close. I didn't see you said you did ecdf(binsx) which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I figured it was x, but my sampnum was way too large for me to check, so I thought it was incorrect. Holy snap, been trying to do this all night/morning. THANKS A LOT :))))))))))

Comment: Could you please explain why you suggest the empirical cdf rather than the normally distributed cdf?

Comment: @kkuilla x is not strictly normal. It is the central **limit** theory. For 12 inputs the result is distinctly not normal. You can do a qqplot of x to see. Also the OP had used the the normal cdf in their original code, so I presumed that wasn't what they wanted!

Comment: Please note that I am not having a rant. I can accept that the OP wanted to use something other than `normcdf()` but what I don't understand is why `ecdf()` is a better solution than `normcdf`. The whole point of the CLT is that you can approximate any distribution with a normal as long as the samples > 28. Therefore `normcdf` would be the choice here, not `ecdf`. I think the OPs original code works just as well. No need for `ecdf`. (imho)

Comment: @kkuilla - I agree with your assessment.  I was confused as to why `ecdf` should be used here when the original code is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Generate `N` replicates of `x`, where N should be several thousand or tens of thousands. Then `p-hat = count(x > 365) / N`, and has a standard error of `sqrt[p-hat * (1 - p-hat) / N]`.  The larger the number of replications is, the smaller the margin of error will be for the estimate.

When I did this in JMP with `N`=10,000 I ended up with `[0.2039, 0.2199]` as a 95% CI for the true proportion of the time that a box of bulbs lasts more than a year.  The discrepancy with your value of 0.2265, along with a histogram of the 10,000 outcomes, indicates that actual distribution is still somewhat skewed.  In other words, using a CLT approximation for the sum of 12 exponentials is going to give answers that are slightly off.